# Comparing null Character with character throws exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why does the following throw a NPE?

```
Character c = null;
if(c == ' ') {   
  System.out.println("Is space");  
}
```

Is this some syntactical sugar for `c.equals(' ')`?

Comment: always use the literal first: (' ' == c)

Comment: it is syntactic sugar, not for `c.equals(' ')`, but for `c.charValue() == ' '`

Comment: @Turo that won't make a difference. It will still throw a `NullPointerException`. However, that comparison reordering is a very good practice for `equals` tests.

Comment: @Turo: That is C/C++ style and not used in java.

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly. The operation `c == ' '` is equivalent to `c.charValue() == ' '`, so when `charValue()` is invoked on `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

This is an "unboxing" operation on `c`, rather than a "boxing" of `' '` followed by an `equals()` test.

Answer (score 4):

During the processing of the equality operator `==`, [binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) occurs.

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> *Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)*.

[Unboxing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> - If `r` is `null`, unboxing conversion throws a `NullPointerException`

The JVM sees `Character` and `char` as the operands.  They are convertible to numeric types, so it unboxes the `Character`.  The `Character` is `null`, so that explains the NPE.

It may be considered "syntactic sugar", but only because it automatically performs the unboxing for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
Character c = null;
if(c != null) {   
  if(c.equals(' ')) {   
  System.out.println("Is space");  
}    
} else{System.out.println("c is null !!!");  }
```